# Нестандартные сетки Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Я начала разбираться в Bootstrap. Не могу понять как с помощью него можно создавать не обычные сетки. Например чтобы блоки занимали не только разную ширину, но и разную высоту.

Вот пример сетки, который легко можно сделать с помощью CSS Grid, но я не понимаю как вот такое можно сделать на бутстрапе, чтобы оно легко адаптивно изменялось согласно макетам.

[image: Десктопная версия]

[image: Планшетная версия]

[image: Мобильная версия]

Comment: На изображениях - 3 версии сетки для десктопа, планшета и мобильная версия

Comment: Если вы можете это реализовать гридом, то зачем вам бутстрап сетка для этого?

Comment: Потому что работодатель требует использовать бутстап, так как IE и Opera Mini не поддеривают грид.

Comment: Используйте `float`

Comment: Для css grid можно еще воспользоваться polyfill https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0 card-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" src="..." alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3 text-right">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Используйте masonry. В [документации](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) есть